# Jquery attr method does not work on 'onMouseEnter'

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the real situation:
As I said I have 12 different DIV's and a page like this.I have linked the js file already
index.html:

```
 <div id="images_puzzle">
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
   <div>
       <img />
       <p></p>
   </div>
       </div>


</div>
```

Notive the I have combined Jquery.js with my own js file.
this is where I can't get what I want. By hovering the mouse over each image I want to call a function, all other attributes are working well but this one is not.

webroot.js:

```
function setPuzzleImages() {
// alert('loading images...');
var $index = 1;
var $IMGs = $('#images_puzzle IMG');
$IMGs.each(function () {
$(this).attr({ 'src': 'images/105-100/' + $index + '.jpg','onmouseover':'showTitle('+$index+');'});
    $index++;
});
}

function showTitle($index) {
alert('this is the'+$index+'image');
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation please

Comment: @AliRashidi google `.prop()` it doesn't need more explanation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vQ366/ works perfectly fine

Comment: can you show your markup for those 12 divs!?

Comment: why do you say `mouseover` does not do what you want

Comment: @Pilot Yes that works but I exactly do the same but still no action :(

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I could see is that the method showTitle may not be in the global scope so try

```
$myImg = $('img')
$myImg.attr({
    src: 'myPic.png'
}).mouseover(showTitle);

function showTitle() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y9PRB/)

Your ode works fine if you add the method to global scope

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y9PRB/2/)

---

Based on the update

```
function setPuzzleImages() {
    var $IMGs = $('#images_puzzle IMG');
    $IMGs.mouseover(showTitle).attr('src', function (i) {
        return 'images/105-100/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg'
    })
}

function showTitle() {
    console.log('Hello World', this);
}
```

Comment: as I said I dont want to use jquery mouseover method

Comment: @AliRashidi - Why not?

Comment: @EdHeal I need to set individual attributes for individual img's.

Comment: @AliRashidi - So how is using mouseover method prevents you doing this?

Comment: Using Jquery.mouseover sets the given attribute to all the images. Each img has an index, sorry I have not mentioned that here, Your answers works for this situation but not for mine :(

Comment: @AliRashidi I don't see you using the index value for the mouseover attribute, it is used for only the src attribute

Comment: When I manually write the onmouseover attribute to an img it works, but with jquery it does not.

Comment: @ArunPJohny What's that? where is the mouseover event handler?

Comment: @AliRashidi unless you can recreate the problem we can't do much... you can try out the second solution which uses a global scoped function.... I'll not advice to use it... unless you can recreate the problem there is nothing much to be done

Comment: @AliRashidi did you see the `console.log()`... it logs to your browser console... using `alert()` to debug code is always disturbing

Comment: @AliRashidi open your browser console to see the event handler logging the messages or change the `console.log()` to an `alert()`